# Graph Engine visualization

Tags: distributed-computing, in-memory, graphengine

is there any source or binary for the utility shown here? Or may be some kind of alternative?

https://www.graphengine.io/video/likq.video.html

Comment: I've found a few samples here: https://github.com/Microsoft/GraphEngine/tree/master/samples

Comment: I asked the same thing here https://github.com/Microsoft/GraphEngine/issues/182.  The GraphEngine team are thinking about it.